# SonarQube Java 'NullPointerException might be thrown' in if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, nullpointerexception, sonarqube

I get a kind of following error from solarQube = "
**NullPointerException might be thrown as 'a' is nullable here**". Below is simple code sample for the error.

The class :

```
class A {
int a1;
int a2;

public A () {
}

public int getA1() {
    return a1;
}

public int getA2() {
    return a2;
}
}
```

Then I have a method which use the class above as param :

```
public boolean testMethod(A a) {
    if(a != null && a.getA1() != 1 || a.getA2() != 2) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;   
}
```

I got the error with `a.getA2 != 2` highlighted by SonarQube. I just cannot understand the problem with those statement. The description of the bug describes by the SonarQube did not makes me any clearer. How can I fix it and can anyone please explain to me why it is an error ?

Comment: You are currently trying to access two fields `getA1` and `getA2` instead of calling the methods `getA1()` and `getA2()`. Is that intended? Because as is this would not compile.

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad. I forgot the parentheses ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think to [the operators precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) : `&&` has higher priority than `||`.
Operators with higher precedence are evaluated before operators with relatively lower precedence.

So you have to understand this statement :

```
if(a != null && a.getA1() != 1 || a.getA2() != 2)
```

as whether it was written :

```
        // Evaluated together       // Evaluated then
if( (a != null && a.getA1() != 1) || a.getA2() != 2)
```

So `a.getA2() != 2` doesn't have a `null` check.

What you have to write to prevent `NullPointerException` is grouped the evaluation of the two boolean expressions that need to.
You can do it by surrounding them by parenthesis  :

```
if(a != null && (a.getA1() != 1 || a.getA2() != 2))
```

Comment: Cool! It is worked for me. But I still couldn't get to understand. Is it operator && or the statement put inside a parentheses that have higher priority? Oh and anyway, thanks.

Comment: You welcome. I updated anyway :) `&&` has higher priority than `||`. So to group `A && B || C` in this way `A &&`  the result of `B || C` you have to add parentheses such as : `A && (B || C)`